# Stopping Running Server with Java Code?

Tags: java

I want to stop a server running on port 8080. In my java application, whenever application is closed, also this server needs to be stopped. But I could not find any solution except stopping the server manually. Is there any way to stop a server with codes ? By the way, I am using Windows 7

Comment: Is it e.g. an Apache server, or is it a server you developed yourself? The way to go about it would be totally different if so.

Comment: is it a standalone java application or an web based?

Comment: I want to send a command which will provide stopping running on port 8080. Thats I want to stop this localhost:8080 server via a command to be sent command promt. This server looks like apache server. SymmetricDs server. This server configures database schronization.

Comment: This server is not my developed server, it is SymmetricDs server

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you starting SymmetricDs? As a windows service, as a WAR or embedded in you application?

Looking at the user guide it seems that if you could embed it in your code you ought to be able to start and stop it directly. More details in the [user guide](http://symmetricds.codehaus.org/guide/2.x/html-single/user-guide.html#deployment-options-embedded) along with the following example code.

```
import org.jumpmind.symmetric.SymmetricWebServer;

public class StartSymmetricEngine {

    /**
     * Start an engine that is configured by two properties files. One is
     * packaged with the application and contains overridden properties that are
     * specific to the application. The other is found in the application's
     * working directory. It can be used to setup environment specific
     * properties.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        SymmetricWebServer node = new SymmetricWebServer(
                                   "classpath://my-application.properties");

        // this will create the database, sync triggers, start jobs running
        node.start(8080);

        // this will stop the node
        node.stop();
    }   

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
    // Execute a command to terminate your server
    String command = "command to stop your server";
    Process child = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);

} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

Comment: Well, What is necessary command ?. For example, My server running on port 8080 PID is 2684

Comment: @Suresh, I am using windows OS

Comment: `taskkill /PID 2684` or better to use command for example you want to shutdown tomcat just execute `shutdown.bat` from appropriate path

Answer (score 0):

Since i did not see the code , how are creating server and accepting connection ,below
i have given you the following ooptions.you should try to implement the firstway , 
rest of the option wont guarantee whether correct process will be killed.

1. > ```
   >  public void stopServer()
   > {
   >   threadReference.interrupt();
   > }
   >
   > while(!Thread.interrupted())
   > {
   >
   >    //   Accept Server Connection
   >    try 
   >    {
   >     Thread.sleep(1000);
   >    } 
   >    catch(InterruptedException ex)  
   >    { 
   >      Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); 
   >    }
   > }
   >
   > Runtime.getRunTime().addShutDownHook(new Thread()
   > {
   >   public void run()
   >   {
   >     try 
   >     {  
   >       ref.stop();
   >     }  catch (IOException e)  
   >     { 
   >       // close server socket
   >       // other clean up 
   >       e.printStackTrace();  
   >     }  
   >   }
   > });
   > ```
2. you need to specify this in Runtime.getRuntime() **TASKKILL /F /IM** or there is a **jps** which is better to kill relevant process.

   > ```
   > try
   > ```
   >
   > {

   ```
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("TASKKILL /F /IM  communicator*"); 
   BufferedReader in = 
   new BufferedReader(new  InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
   ```

> ```
>     String result = null;  
>     while ((result= in.readLine()) != null) {  
>      if ( "SUCCESS".equals(result.substring(0,7))
>      {
>       break;
>      }
>     }  
> } catch (IOException e) 
> {  
>    e.printStackTrace();  
> }
> ```

Comment: exec("taskkill /PID 2684") is this true ?

Comment: @yuce i didnt understand above one.

Comment: exec("Necassary command to stop service localhost:8080") What is necassary command prompt command ?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you check [Cargo](http://cargo.codehaus.org/)? It provides a Java API to start/stop Java containers. You can find the list of supported containers in the home page.

Comment: Let me tell you a question ? If you have a server running on localhost:8080 like xammp apache server, how do you stop this server by just clicking a button? What I mean is that I just want to stop this server when my application is closed. That's I want to send a command to command prompt for stopping this 8080 port.

Comment: First check in task manager , under what name the server is running , then try this command in cmd prompt TASKKILL /F FI "WINDOWTITLE eq <process name in windows task manager>*"

Comment: @Suresh I created a bat file containing running server codes. Then I executed this bat file Runtime rn=Runtime.getRuntime(); Process pr=rn.exec("main/resources/RunPort8080.bat"); This code there is no error. But when my program closed, server still runnig. I do not know why it is still running. When I run RunPort8080.bat file in Command Prompt then close command prompt server not runnig. The problem is lack of "pr.exit();" statement ?

Comment: @Yuce did you look at Richard Miskin comments,

Comment: @Suresh Yes I looked at, I see this codes before. My question is general not covering symmetric ds servers but including all windows servers.